# the JSONArray is empty when I get it in js function from struts2 action,I cannot figure out why

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, struts2

this is my `struts.xml`:

```
<package name="ajax" namespace="/" extends="json-default">
   <action name="checkMembers" class="com.mytest.action.InfoCheck">
      <result name="success" type="json" >
            <param name="includeProperties">myresult</param>
      </result> 
  </action>
```

this is my action function

```
 @Override
public String execute() throws Exception {
    Student stu = new Student(); //stu has only two fields,name and passwd  
    stu.setName("cxg");
    stu.setPasswd("ddd");
    set.add(stu);
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();      
    jsonArray=JSONArray.fromObject(set);  
    myresult=jsonArray;
    System.out.println(myresult.toString());
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

**The println function result is [{"name":"cxg","passwd":"ddd"}]**

but when I get it in $.ajax() i cannot get the result,if like

```
success:function(data){alert(JSON.stringify(data));},
```

the alert result is {"myresult":[]},
However ,if myresult is type of string,the alert would be 
`**{"myresult":"[{\"name\":\"rxg\",\"passwd\":\"ddd\"}]"}**`,I don't think it is right neither
,Please help me figure out why,and how can I get the right jsonarray

Comment: What happens if you open the url in a browser? Does it look like valid JSon, what do the response headers look like (press F12 in Chrome check out network tab)?

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't need to convert to json, when you're using struts2-json-plugin.
2. All the objects/fields referenced in the action, will automatically be converted to a valid json by the plugin.
3. Just remove the `includeProperties` from the configuration & you'll get the set, directly as a Json array.
4. If you wish to include or exclude certain fields, you can use `includeProperties` & `excludeProperties`
5. [Documentation](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/json-plugin.html) - It'll help you understand better the concept.

[EDIT]

1. Extend struts-default, unless you're really wishing to define the interceptor set, results etc. So change your package configuration to :

   `<package name="ajax" namespace="/" extends="json-default,struts-default">`